# Ext JS Iframe GET request

Tags: dom, iframe, extjs

I want to get server response displayed using alert by

```
    Ext.getBody().mask('Downloading file....', 'x-mask-loading');
    var iframe = Ext.getBody().createChild({
        tag: 'iframe',
        cls: 'x-hidden',
        src: downldObj.url
    });
    iframe.on('readystatechange', function () {
        if (iframe.dom.readyState === 'loading') {
            return;
        }
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
        iframe.remove.defer(1000, iframe);
    });
```

How to I get the server response alert to user
from the server code I am doing
Response.status(Status.Error ,"Downloading falied","application/json").header("Content-Type", "text/html")